# Why are styrene acrylate copolymers used for toner?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I have been scratching my head lately, after learning that laser printer toners are often made from *styrene-acrylate* copolymers. As of yet, I have not found information on these polymers in reference texts or papers/research outside of the realm of xerography, electrophotography, and other printing technologies. **What properties make these polymers particularly interesting for toners, but completely uninteresting to other fields**? At risk of overreaching, I'm also curious how these copolymers came to be used in toner in the first place, given the lack of convenient information?

References:

1. *Reactive Polymers Fundamentals and Applications*, chapter 20 "Toners"
2. *Production of carbon black acrylic composite as an electrophotographic toner using emulsion aggregation method:
   Investigation the effect of agitation rate*, paper by Maryam
   Ataeefard
3. *Production of black toner through emulsion aggregation of magnetite, carbon black, and styrene-acrylic co-polymer:
   Investigation on the effect of variation in components*, paper by
   Maryam Ataeefard
4. Various MSDS pages from toner and laser printer manufacturers

Comment: Suitably tuned Tg, so it's a powder but melts to the paper easily. Easiest way to tune is likely to make a copolymer. Low Mw plastisisers are not tolerable, because they would boild out in the fixer. Electrostatic properties, so the transfer to the paper works reliably.